# SQLite not using index when using concatenation

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using the following SQL statement for SQLite:

```
select * from words where \"word\" like ? || '%' || ? ;
```

In order to bind parameters to the first and last letters. I have tested this both with and without an index on the column `word`, and the results are the same. However, when running the queries as

```
select * from words where \"word\" like 'a%a';
```

etc. (that is, hardcoding each value instead of using `||`, the query is about x10 faster when indexed.

Can someone show me how to use the index and the parameters both?

Comment: You could try `EXPLAIN ...` to get some details about the execution plan of the query, maybe there'll be some clue there?

Comment: @Kerrek-SB I tried `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` and it is as I said. One uses the index, the other doesn't.

Comment: Can you add more context such as some code running those SQL queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to the sqlite mailing list. It says here (http://sqlite.org/optoverview.html), section 4: "The right-hand side of the LIKE or GLOB must be either a string literal or a parameter bound to a string literal that does not begin with a wildcard character."